# Trouble in Internationalisation, iOS

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

I need to internationalize some of the labels in a screen; do I need to localize the whole screen?
One more doubt, I have taken a string file and pulling the value of the keys from that file directly from that file using `NSLocalizedString`, then also do I need to localize the screen or it will by default get localized?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 you need not to localize the whole screen.
 for two label only, on viewdidLoad

 self.lbe1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Label1", nil)
 self.lbe2.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Label2", nil)

 your second doubt is not clear to me.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the localize file. Then label you can use the localized id. Then you don't need to worry the whole screen or particular screen or particular text. Because whatever you can change.  If you want more info refer this link
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014